# ubuntu 12.10 high temperature

Tags: 12.10, hp, overheating, gpu

i have an hp g6 with ubuntu 12.10 (64), when i watch a flash in full screen or play even a small ubuntu game like chess, the temperature goes to 80-90 degrees, normal browsing temperatures 64-70,  i have a dual gpu, i read a lot of posts here and in ubuntu forums and now im lost dont know what to do, i've read about vgaswitcheroo but i cant manage to install or enable it, changing gpu from the catalyst to power saving doesnt help, please someone advise.

`root@simo:/# lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Caicos [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

`root@simo:/# fglrxinfo`

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6400M Series
OpenGL version string: 4.2.12002 Compatibility Profile Context 9.012
```

`simo@simo:~$ lspci | grep VGA`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Caicos [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]
```

`simo@simo:~$ grep -i switcheroo /boot/config-*`

```
/boot/config-3.2.0-38-generic:CONFIG_VGA_SWITCHEROO=y
/boot/config-3.5.0-25-generic:CONFIG_VGA_SWITCHEROO=y
simo@simo:~$
```

`root@simo:/# ls -l /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`

```
ls: cannot access /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch: No such file or directory
root@simo:/#
```

Comment: Your hardware is probably not connected well with the heatsink. Check your fan too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did somehow solved it, temperatures are now 55-60 - installed manually the driver from hp website : amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-linux-x86.x86_64 + jupiter with option power on demand
hope this will help someone
cheers